# Blank content is displayed when trying to open .pdf in another tab using React and Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, pdf, react-context

I am trying to open a .pdf in another tab that is stored in the server's file system (I am using Express, React and MySQL).
When the user clicks the "See" button, the `displayCV` function is executed, and a new tab is open, but the .pdf content is blank even though the new tab shows the correct number of pages the .pdf contains.

The flow goes like this:

**JobItem.jsx**

```
const displayCV = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   await displayCurriculum();
};
```

**JobContext.js**

```
const displayCurriculum = async () => {
  const { id } = params;

  const response = await axios.get(`/api/jobs/${id}/cv`);
  // console.log(response);

  const file = new Blob([response.data], {
    type: "application/pdf",
  });

  const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const pdfWindow = window.open();
  pdfWindow.location.href = fileURL;
};
```

The backend looks like this:

**jobRoutes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { displayCurriculum } = require("../controllers/jobController");
router.route("/:id/cv").get(displayCurriculum);
```

**jobController.js**

```
const displayCurriculum = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params,
      q = `SELECT curriculum FROM jobs WHERE idjobs = ?`,
      doc = await pool.query(q, [id]);

    const fileName = doc[0].curriculum;

    // const data = fs.readFileSync(filesPath + "\\" + fileName);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    res.sendFile(fileName, { root: filesPath }, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log("Sent: ", fileName);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

If I use Postman and hit the API's endpoint (`/api/jobs/${id}/cv`) the .pdf is displayed correctly in Postman. When hitting the endpoint from the frontend I get the following
[Image with blank .pdf content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7b5U.png)

How can I display the .pdf content in the new tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, it turns out that the `responseType` from Axios needs to be set to `"blob"` for the .pdf to be read.

**JobContext.js**

```
 const displayCurriculum = async () => {
    const { id } = params;
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/jobs/${id}/cv`, {
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "blob",
    });

    const file = new Blob([response.data], {
      type: "application/pdf",
    });

    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
 };
```

The .pdf is now opening in a new tab and is showing its content. However, the name of the file in the URL is set to the [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) that is created by `URL.createObjectURL()`. If the user tries to download the .pdf, the default filename will be the DOMString generated.

Example URL:

> blob:http://localhost:3000/c6430bc7-99b3-4dae-9caf-79997f801752

Comment: that was my problem as well thanks